# Connecting Dockerized App to MySQL using Windows command returns error

Tags: mysql, docker, cmd, docker-container

**After 5 hours of unsuccessful research.**
Following a [Docker Lab](https://github.com/docker/getting-started) tutorial, have successfully built and run the dockerized app. However in step 7 Connecting the App to MySQL, While running this command on windows CMD:

```
    docker run -dp 3000:3000 ^
    -w /app -v "cd:/app" ^
    --network todo-app ^
    -e MYSQL_HOST=mysql ^
    -e MYSQL_USER=root ^
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret ^
    -e MYSQL_DB=todos ^
    node:12-alpine ^
    sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

The CMD returns this error:

```
9165fe85fbd4c98b9f9455509081252fa89f8f6e072e6caa2651b5a062bc8927
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 
pensive_meitner (97c005c64c2f6ab1dabb8106a3b57285ba610717b36fd3ec82f1c97ad7efa648): Bind for 
0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated.
```

[CMD Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pruxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a container which is listening on port `3000`, container_id: `04cda...`

Stop it: `docker stop 04cda0bb547f`

Then `docker run` again, please take a another name if name of container is duplicated.